# Windows Batch Variable within variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

In windows batch could you set a variable within a variable?

Explained:

So the %num% is within the variable.

```
set num=5
set cnum=test
set h1=%c%num%%
```

Is it possible to make the percents work like parenthesis?
The output should be h1=test

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example in your question is a mess, but I think I understand what you are looking for:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set C1=apple
set C2=orange
set C3=banana

set num=2


:: Inefficient way without delayed expansion
:: This will be noticeably slow if used in a tight loop with many iterations
call echo %%C%num%%%

:: The remaining methods require delayed expansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Efficient way 1
echo(
echo !C%num%!

:: Efficient way 2 - useful if inside parenthesized block
:: where %num% will not give current value
echo(
for %%N in (!num!) do echo !C%%N!

:: Showing all values via a loop
echo(
for /l %%N in (1 1 3) do echo !C%%N!
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for the Call Set command. This sets cnum to string c1, c2, c3 etc. It changes each time %num% changes. You can then use Call Set to assign any variable (h1 for example) to the value of the variable cnum stands for.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set c5=test
    set num=5

    :: set cnum to string "c5"
        set cnum=c%num%
    :: set h1 to to the existing variable c5 
        call set "h1=%%%cnum%%%"
        echo %h1%
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you after something like this?

```
cls
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set num=5
Set "c!num!=test"
Echo !c5!
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html for more info on delayed expansion.

```
cls
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set num=4
set c1=this is a demo
set c2=second example
set c3=third
set c4=this is the one I want
set c5=last
Echo !c%num%!
```

Comment: Sort of, It's like that only reversed. I'm trying to avoid having to script a lot more than I need to and call a predefined variable that varies according to certain conditions, example:

Comment: set value=%start%number%% where the %number% can be changed.

Comment: start1, start2, start3 etc. are already defined variables, I just need to load certain variables according to the %number% variable.