# Is it possible to make a randomly generated variable in batch?

Tags: batch-file, random

Currently I am making a game in batch that has randomly generated worlds. I'm currently working on biome generation, and I'm trying to figure out a way to have each variable generated, so the variables will look like `%biomenum[0,0]%`, `%biomenum[0,1]%`, and going maybe as far as `%biomenum[512,512]%` and as low as `%biomenum[-512,-512]`

The code that I have currently generates the biome for 9 different chunks, but it doesn't make the variables itself, and typing this out for each chunk between -512, -512 and 512, 512 doesn't seem all that plausible

```
rem 0x 0y
set /A biomenum0x0y = %RANDOM% * 16 / 32768 + 1
rem 0x 1y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenum0x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenum0x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenum0x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenum0x1y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem 1x 1y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenum1x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenum1x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenum1x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenum1x1y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem 1x 0y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenum1x0y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenum1x0y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenum1x0y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenum1x0y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem 1x -1y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenum1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenum1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenum1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenum1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem 0x -1y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenum0xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenum0xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenum0xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenum0xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem -1x -1y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenumneg1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenumneg1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenumneg1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenumneg1xneg1y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem -1x 0y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenumneg1x0y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenumneg1x0y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenumneg1x0y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenumneg1x0y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
rem -1x 1y
set /A nextbiomenum = %RANDOM% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "1" set /A biomenumneg1x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 1
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "2" set /A biomenumneg1x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "3" set /A biomenumneg1x1y =  biomenum0x0y + 0
if /I "%nextbiomenum%" EQU "4" set /A biomenumneg1x1y =  biomenum0x0y - 1
echo %biomenumneg1xneg1y% is the biome for -1,-1
echo %biomenumneg1x0y% is the biome for -1, 0
echo %biomenumneg1x1y% is the biome for -1, 1
echo %biomenum0xneg1y% is the biome for 0, -1
echo %biomenum0x0y% is the biome for 0, 0 -the starting chunk-
echo %biomenum0x1y% is the biome for 0, 1
echo %biomenum1xneg1y% is the biome for 1, -1
echo %biomenum1x0y% is the biome for 1, 0
echo %biomenum1x1y% is the biome for 1, 1
```

How would I be able to automate the creation of variables, so I don't have to type out all 1,048,576 chunks?

*Note: This question was edited so it made more sense. The original was a very long explanation that I made on 3 hours of sleep, and I apologize for that. Hopefully this is a bit more easy to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variable within variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114936/windows-batch-variable-within-variable)

Comment: Just realized that this question has already been asked at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114936/windows-batch-variable-within-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is pretty confusing, both in what you want to get and the way to obtain it...

When you have a *series of variables* with the same name and you want to *select* one variable based on the value of another variable (called *index*), then the name for such a *data structure* is [*array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type). If the array *elements* are selected by just one index variable (one dimensional array), then it is usually called *vector*. If the array elements are selected by two or more indices (multi-dimensional array), then it is called *matrix*.

In computer programs the usual way to repeat *the same code* over a range of values that are all processed in the same way is via the FOR statement/construct/command. The FOR *control variable* is placed in the code in the place of the varying value. The usual way to process a series of array elements is via a FOR command and place its control variable as the index of the array element.

The way to process array elements in Batch file programs is described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

The next Batch file obtain a result equivalent than your example code, but using a two-dimensional array and two nested FOR commands:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem 0x 0y
set /A biomenum0x0y = %RANDOM% * 16 / 32768 + 1
rem The rest!
for %%x in (neg1 0 1) do (
   for %%y in (neg1 0 1) do (
      set /A nextbiomenum = !RANDOM! * 4 / 32768 - 1, biomenum%%xx%%yy = biomenum0x0y + nextbiomenum %% 2
   )
)

echo %biomenumneg1xneg1y% is the biome for -1,-1
echo %biomenumneg1x0y% is the biome for -1, 0
echo %biomenumneg1x1y% is the biome for -1, 1
echo %biomenum0xneg1y% is the biome for 0, -1
echo %biomenum0x0y% is the biome for 0, 0 -the starting chunk-
echo %biomenum0x1y% is the biome for 0, 1
echo %biomenum1xneg1y% is the biome for 1, -1
echo %biomenum1x0y% is the biome for 1, 0
echo %biomenum1x1y% is the biome for 1, 1
```

The results obtained by this code are not *exactly the same* than your code. In your code you add 1 when random is 1 and subtract 1 when random is 4 (and ignore 2 and 3). In my simplification I generate a number between -1 and 2 (instead of 1 to 4) and add 1 when random is 1 and subtract 1 when random is -1 (and ignore 0 and 2); this is done taking the remainder (mod, `%` operator) of the number divided by 2. The statistical result is, however, the same...

Antonio

PS - I suggest you to use the *standard array notation* with the subscripts enclosed in square braquets, (like `%biomenum[1,0]%` or `%biomenum[1][0]%`instead of `%biomenum1x0y%` ) for the reasons explained at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544646/dir-output-into-bat-array/10569981#10569981).

Comment: Sorry about the explanation of the question, sometimes when I'm writing I can go on a bit of a tangent, but this was exactly what I was looking for!